# jquery mobile, theming back button doesn't work

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have back button on certain pages of my (single page) html/css/js app.

```html
<div id="explanation-page1" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Back">
```

I inserted this in my js file to use data-theme="a" for these back buttons:

```js
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnTheme = "a";
});
```

but it doesn't work, the back button is still using theme "b" (blue).

Any idea?
Thanks
ps: I just tried to create a js fiddle (first one for me) but it doesn't even show the back button...don't know why? http://jsfiddle.net/9Yfcs/

Comment: what jQM version are u using?

Comment: Are you binding to `mobileinit` *before* including jQuery Mobile?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi ok I think I understand that I have to put this command into the jquery.mobile.config.js file, is this right?

Comment: If your script file is named like that, yes. In the general case, you have to bind to `mobileinit` after including jQuery and before including jQuery Mobile.

Comment: ok I see, I just wrote my own answer from this. Isn't it possible to do it later though?

Comment: @Louis, it's too late if you do that later, as jQuery Mobile will already have enforced the back button theme.

Comment: ok then, thanks for your very quick answers.

Answer (score 2):

Ok thanks to FrédéricHamidi I got the solution, I just put the

```js
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnTheme = "a";
});
```

into the file jquery.mobile.config.js file, and included it before jquery mobile in the html file, like this:

```html
<script src="js/jquery.mobile.config.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>
```